# Errors in Unit Test project when including file from main project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I am currently learning Unit Testing in Visual Studio 2015 but I am finding it hard to find good resources on the topic.

I have set up a C++ Native Unit Test project in the same solution as my main project. I then Set up the main project as a reference in the test project.

My issue is, when I include a file from the main project in the test, almost every single function is giving out compiler errors like these.

[image: Errors]

This is the test class

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Util\fileutil.h>

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;


namespace EngineTest
{       
using namespace Engine;
TEST_CLASS(EngineTests)
{
public:

    TEST_METHOD(UnitTestTest)
    {
        int i = 1;
        Assert::IsTrue(i == 1);
    }

    TEST_METHOD(FilePathSplit)
    {
        FileUtils testClass;
        std::string examplePath = "./FolderOne/FolderTwo/File.file";
        std::string exampleName = "File.file";
        std::set<char> delims{ '\\', '/' };
        std::string fileName = testClass.test_splitpath(examplePath, delims).back();
        Assert::AreSame(fileName, exampleName);

    }

};
}
```

The build works just fine, so I assume it is an issue with dependencies not being loaded in, I have tried adding all the headers into stdafx but that did not change anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so it was a stupid issue.

The main project was set to support Multi-Byte character sets and the other was set to use Unicode. So all the errors where me trying to convert const char* into win32 formats and it didnt like it.

Properties -> General -> Character Sets